# Minha função assincrona não retorna o valor onde é chamada, mas dentro de seu escopo está funcionando certo. Reactjs + google maps

Tags: react, google-maps

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from "google-maps-react";
import { MAPS_API_TOKEN, GEOCODE_API_TOKEN } from 
"../Enviroments/dev";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

const mapStyles = {
width: "100%",
height: "100%"
};

var labelIndex = 0;
// var description = "Pão";

function getLabelIndex() {
labelIndex++;
return labelIndex.toString();
}

Geocode.setApiKey(GEOCODE_API_TOKEN);

class SimpleMap extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  resultado: ""
};

this.getDetail = this.getDetail.bind(this);
}

getMarkers() {
if (typeof this.props.locations !== "undefined") {
  return this.props.locations.map(location => (
    <Marker
      title={this.getDetail(location)}
      label={getLabelIndex()}
      key={location.time}
      position={{
        lat: location.latitude,
        lng: location.longitude
      }}
    />
  ));
}
}

getDetail(location) {
this.getDescription(location).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  return result;
});
}

getDescription(location) {
 var address = "Não foi possível carregar o endereço";

 Geocode.fromLatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude).then(
  status, response => {
    if(status === 'OK')
    address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
  }
);

const formatedTime = this.getFormatedTime(location.time);

const description =
  "Data: " +
  formatedTime.date +
  "\nHora: " +
  formatedTime.horary +
  "\nEndereço: " +
  address;

return description;

}

getFormatedTime(time) {
const yyyy = time.slice(0, 4);
const MM = time.slice(4, 6);
const dd = time.slice(6, 8);

const hh = time.slice(8, 10);
const mm = time.slice(10, 12);
const ss = time.slice(12, 14);

const formatedTime = {
  horary: hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss,
  date: dd + "/" + MM + "/" + yyyy
};

return formatedTime;
}

  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Map
      google={this.props.google}
      zoom={8}
      style={mapStyles}
      initialCenter={this.props.zoom_position}
      center={this.props.zoom_position}
    >
      {(labelIndex = 0)}
      {this.getMarkers()}
    </Map>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: MAPS_API_TOKEN
})(SimpleMap);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

valor dentro da função getDetail está ok, mas onde chamo a mesma e passo os dados, ela n mostra o valor ao passar o mouse por cima do marcador. O que pode ser o erro?

Comment: Tem muitas coisas erradas nesse código. Primeiro você não usa then quando usa await, isso se torna irrelevante. Depois, você precisa ter um estado, Pois como está manipulando muitas promises é bom você ter um render quando o valor ser alterado.Sendo assim, coloque seu código inteiro, para que possamos ajudar. E por ultimo evite usar `var`.

Comment: coloquei todo o código, como pediu

Comment: tinha colocado um estado para receber o resultado em getDetail, mas sempre que eu passava o mesmo, caia em um loop

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente eu mudei o seguinte, a função `getDescription` vai retornar o resultado dentro de uma função callback passado para ela. Isso irá retornar em `getDetail` que pegará o a descrição e irá inserir no estado, criei um array de objeto chamado resultados. Dentro desse array será recebido um objeto com os valores `location` e `detail(description)`. Sendo assim o render será feito. Para não ficar sendo chamado várias vezes como você mencionou do loop, eu adicionei dentro do componentDidMount. E no `getMarkers` ao invés de fazer um map nas props, eu apenas faço um map no array que está no estado que acabei de criar. Eu achei bem estranho esse seu método getLabelIndex... Me parece uma gambiarra, por isso ao invés de ter uma variável global que fica sendo incrementada, eu apenas usei o index da função map

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from "google-maps-react";
import { MAPS_API_TOKEN, GEOCODE_API_TOKEN } from 
"../Enviroments/dev";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

const mapStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%"
};

Geocode.setApiKey(GEOCODE_API_TOKEN);

class SimpleMap extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resultados: []
    };

    this.getDetail = this.getDetail.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.locations.map(location => (
        this.getDetail(location)
      )
    );
  }

  getMarkers() {
    if (this.state.resultados.length > 0) {
      return this.state.resultados.map((resultado,index) => (
        <Marker
          title={resultado.detail}
          label={index.toString()}
          key={resultado.location.time}
          position={{
            lat: resultado.location.latitude,
            lng: resultado.location.longitude
          }}
        />
      ));
    }
  }

  getDetail(location) {
    this.getDescription(location, (description) => {
      this.setState(state => {
        const resultado = state.resultados.concat({
          location: location,
          detail: description
        })

        return {
          resultados: resultado
        }
      })
    })
  }

  getDescription(location, callback) {
    Geocode.fromLatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude).then(
      status, response => {
        if(status === 'OK'){
          const address = response.results[0].formatted_address || "Não foi possível carregar o endereço";
          const formatedTime = this.getFormatedTime(location.time);
          const description =
            "Data: " +
            formatedTime.date +
            "\nHora: " +
            formatedTime.horary +
            "\nEndereço: " +
            address;

          callback(description);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getFormatedTime(time) {
    const yyyy = time.slice(0, 4);
    const MM = time.slice(4, 6);
    const dd = time.slice(6, 8);

    const hh = time.slice(8, 10);
    const mm = time.slice(10, 12);
    const ss = time.slice(12, 14);

    const formatedTime = {
      horary: hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss,
      date: dd + "/" + MM + "/" + yyyy
    };

    return formatedTime;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={8}
          style={mapStyles}
          initialCenter={this.props.zoom_position}
          center={this.props.zoom_position}
        >
          {this.getMarkers()}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: MAPS_API_TOKEN
})(SimpleMap);
```